# Error while hosting on render, didn't able to connect with io server( or didn't know how to connect

Tags: node.js, socket.io, render

I am building a chat application with socket.io and for the routes i used express router and for realtime chatting i used socket.io.

The application is running very good in my local server. My backend is running on port 3000 and my socket is running on port 3002. But when i hosted it on render, it gives me an error that, the frontend is not able to connect with my socket.

[link to my repo](https://github.com/Vansh1190/chatverse-backend)

I used io.connect `https://renderUrl.com:3002`

Not working

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should be self-contained. Also, you do not post what are server side errors, and "very urgent" isn't well accepted here...

Answer (score 0):

I see in your `index.js` that you hardcoded the Express port. Do not do that, always use `process.env.PORT || 3000`, because Render needs to pick a free port on server.  Change line 4 of your index.js with something like this:
`const port = process.env.PORT || 3000` 
In this way, if you are in local and `process.env.PORT` is undefined, there is the `3000` fallback